# Find pdf of $W = X/(X+Y)$ - Result check

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function

I come up with this problem and I am sure if my solution is corrected.

> $X, Y \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$. Find pdf of $W = X/(X+Y)$.

Please see my try bellow:

[image]

[image]

At Eq(17) I don't know if my result is corrected or not.

Comment: You should finish simplifying $(17)$ to get $f_W(w) = I_{(0, 1)}(w)$ (i.e., uniform(0, 1) distribution). For a more general case, check [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/596387/link-between-the-beta-and-exponential-distribution/596396#596396).

Comment: Can you explain how the term in $z$ in (17) follows from the term in $z$ at (16)? (You should not take that to imply things are necessarily correct elsewhere)